# Xamarin iOS Custom ListView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm having trouble with the size of a `ListView` within a `StackedLayout`. I want the `ListView` to take only as much space as necessary by the contained items. However, my `ListView` almost always takes up all the space there is, even if it only contains like 3 items or so.

Is there a way to create a custom `DynamicListView` and override certain methods calculating a custom size whenever items are added or removed? For example, I want the list to disappear whenever it's empty. Can anyone tell me, which methods to override and/or how to react on items being added/removed to the underlying model?

My gut feeling tells me something like this:

```
namespace Foo.Controls
{
    public class SpottedView : ListView
    {
        public SpottedView()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnChildAdded(Element child)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Util.methodName()}");
            base.OnChildAdded(child);
            InvalidateMeasure();
        }

        protected override void OnChildRemoved(Element child)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Util.methodName()}");
            base.OnChildRemoved(child);
            InvalidateMeasure();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `ListView` should work as you expected in `RelativeLayout`. I'd investigate this way.

Comment: But how can I achieve the `ListView` to get smaller (shrink), it'll always take up the same amount of space in a `RelativeLayout` right?

Comment: Hmm, can't you just subscribe to item added/removed event and change `ListView` size in it? And you're using `XAML` right? Unfortunately I can't test anything in `Xamarin` but I could do some test in `WPF` to see if I am right at all.

Comment: Well that was my idea, too, but which methods do I have to call or which properties do I have to set in order to invalidate/update everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this. I changed from `StackLayout` to `Grid` as follows:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ctrl:CameraView Grid.Row="0" />
        <ctrl:SpottedView Grid.Row="1" RowHeight="40" />

    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

And then I added a custom `ListView`, a `SpottedView` as follows:

```
namespace Foo.Controls
{
    public class SpottedView : ListView
    {
        ObservableCollection<string> items;

        public SpottedView() : base()
        {
            items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            ItemsSource = items;
            items.CollectionChanged += onItemsChanged;

            // TODO: test purposes, remove later
            var autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            var stateTimer = new Timer(onTimer, autoEvent, 1000, 2000);
        }

        void onItemsChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                HeightRequest = RowHeight * items.Count;
                InvalidateMeasure();
            });
        }

        // TODO test purposes, remove later.
        void onTimer(object state)
        {
            MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                if (items.Count < 2)
                {
                    items.Add("Blah");
                }
                else
                {
                    items.Clear();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: You can mark your answer so that more people can see it.